# Not able to get length of an array

Tags: reactjs

I am able to get the value out when I use {userProfile.displayname} and {userProfile.emailacct} which is Batman and batman@demo.com.

So when I try to count number of reviewers {userProfile.reviewers.length} in the h6 tag, it says **"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"**. But when I tried this `{userProfile.reviewers}`, it printed out `"5fc519fd1849413ffb6e3ee35fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448"`

I don't get it. What am I missing here? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated.

The data below is the console.log(result.data.user) in the useEffect()

```
displayname: "Batman"
emailacct: "batman@demo.com"
reviewers: (2) ["5fc519fd1849413ffb6e3ee3", "5fbb3879e8902d14f8c60448"]
id: "5fb35251888e8d081c06a7fa"



const[userProfile,setUserProfile] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
     Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/user/${userid}`, {withCredentials:true}).then(result => {
        setUserProfile(result.data.user)
        console.log(result.data.user) 
     })     
    },[])

 <h2>{userProfile.displayname}</h2>
 <h4>{userProfile.emailacct}</h4>
                    <div style={{display:"flex",justifyContent:"space-between",width:"120%"}}>
                        <h6>{userProfile.reviewers} reviewers</h6> 
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `userProfile` initial state is an empty array `[]`, so `userProfile.reviewers` is undefined. Any `userProfile.XXX` will be undefined. You can't access properties of undefined.

Comment: the userProfile.displayname is working fine. it is the userProfile.reviewers.length that is not working. But the userProfile.reviewers works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`userProfile` initial state is an empty array `[]`, so `userProfile.reviewers` is undefined. Any `userProfile.XXX` will be undefined. You can't access properties of undefined.

## Suggested Solution

Provide valid initial state to match what is accessed on the initial render.

```
const[userProfile,setUserProfile] = useState({
  displayname: null,
  emailacct: null,
  reviewers: [],
  id: null,
});
```

You may want to also implement some conditional rendering to wait until the data has been fetched.

Comment: Thanks. It still the same. I am not able to get the length to work  <h6>{userProfile.reviewers.length} reviewers</h6>, but it works when I tried this  <h6>{userProfile.reviewers} reviewers</h6> but I get IDs displayed.

Comment: sorry.is working now. thanks alot Drew Reese. I made a mistake and very sorry